# Display a post based off the post ID that is selected

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a client portal were my clients can maintain their projects and leave feedback in Wordpress. I have two custom post types called "Clients" and "Projects" and they each pull information from one another in the backend. When I create a client it automatically generates its postID to a drop down menu on the projects post type were I can assign a client to a project.

What I am trying to accomplish is by displaying all projects that are associated with the selected client on a single page on the front end. The single page will be the client portal, which is generated by the client post type.

Right now it displays all of the projects even the ones that would be assigned to a different client. How would I go about displaying the information correctly?

code for single.php

```
 <?php 
       $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
       $loop = new WP_Query( array(
           'post_type'      => array( 'projects'),
           'posts_per_page' => -1,
           'paged'          => $paged,
           'meta_query'     => array(
           array(
               'key'   => 'client_portal',
               'value' => $client,
              )
            ) 
      )); 
 ?>
```

Register Post Type I am using

Project post type is called => projects

Clients post type is called => client_portal

Thank you

Comment: Should be moved to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ - Do you write the client id to the project post type postmeta? The query you are using relies on you adding postmeta to each project as to what client they are related to.

Comment: the client id gets generated to the project post type. On the projects post  I have the ability to select which client I would like to assign to  that project. I am trying to add each project as to what client they are related to. But the query I am using now seems to be clearing my post on the clients page and not displaying any of my post. @Fraggy